# Error: “Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.” in Android Studio

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

I add an asynctask in my app since it has many data to search but i got error in protected Void doInBackground and it says Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker. My app composed of dialog that has editText and Spinner. Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
doctorLocationEditText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.doctorlocation);

doctorHospital = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerdoctorhospital);
ArrayAdapter<String> hospitalAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Doctor.this,R.layout.spinner_layout, db.getAllHospitalName());
hospitalAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
doctorHospital.setAdapter(hospitalAdapter);

Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btndoctorsearch);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new DoctorSearch().execute();
        dialog.dismiss();
```

This is my asynctask that has error

```
class DoctorSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(Doctor.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            Asycdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            GetSearchDoctor = dbhelper.getDoctorSearch(index2, doctorLocationEditText.getText().toString(), doctorHospital.getSelectedItem().toString());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            lv3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchdoctor_list);
            lv3.setAdapter(new ViewAdapterSearchDoctor());
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Asycdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- You are not supposed to access a UI thread from a Background Thread.
- Get text in onPreExecute() or AsyncTask constructor & pass it to doInBackground.